# Grouped-categories chart styling

Tags: javascript, json, highcharts

I'm creating a chart that has a range [2010 January, 2014 December]. I might have data for each month in between (if no data, it's null) and my idea was to use the grouped-categories plugin in order to create a x axis that shows every month (not the label itself) and group the months in years.

I achieved it using the grouped-categories plugin. I'm using primefaces that calls a Javascript function to display the JSON content as a chart.

```
[a link] http://jsfiddle.net/TFhd7/161/
```

The main issue is that in the x-axis I'd like to make it like a ruler:

- decrease the x-axis height (the thicks size)

I tried tickLength but it doesn't work for grouped-categories chart. Any ideas?

Comment: Unfortunately `tickLength` isn't supported by grouped_categories plugin. The best you can achieve without extra coding is play around with labels font size, like this: http://jsfiddle.net/TFhd7/162/ If this is not enough, find comment in js file: `// render grid for "normal" categories (first-level)` - next ~15 lines is responsible for rendering first row of categories.

Comment: This ALMOST does the trick. The major thicks are still big but the smaller ones are just perfect! :) Thanks. There's lack of info about this.

Comment: Too good to be true. Apparently groupedOptions is not supported by IE.

Comment: IE8 and IE9. I've resolved the IE compatibility removing all the labels from the grouped-categories and added another x-axis, an invisible one, with the years and setted the tickPositions. It is a workaround that, even though requires more coding, is compatible.

Comment: If `groupedOptions` doesn't work on IE8/9, then recreate issue on jsFiddle and report bug on github bug-tracker, please.